# AngularJS: How to use ngOption to iterate data from cached Api call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have an application in which I am making multiple API calls and caching that data for later. Then someone else in the app, I want to retrieve that data and list it in a drop down using ng-option. 
To get the cached data for each call, I am doing

```
var httpCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
var cachedImpactedEntities =  httpCache.get('my api url');
```

This returns an object of an array in an array like so:

```
[200,"[  {  
"entity_id": 1,"entity_desc": "test1"  },  
{"entity_id": 2,"entity_desc": "test2"}]",
{"content-type":"application/json; 
charset=utf-8"},"OK"]
```

What would be a good way to extract just the inside array in quotes and output each "entity_desc" to the drop down using ng-option like:

```
test1
test2
...
```

The way the cached information comes back is confusing me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the following shall be sufficient:

```
$scope.cachedEntities = eval(cachedImpactedEntities[1]);
<select ng-options="item as item.entity_desc for item in cachedEntities track by item.entity_id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

But that means you will need to update "manually" the cachedEntities each time you get the data back from api call.
Consider of using promise construct:

```
$http.get("url+parameters").then(function(data) { $scope.cachedEntities = data}, function(){ // do something on error });
```

Comment: You are a saint. the eval(cachedImpactedEntities[1]) was the game changer

Comment: Follow up: say I want to display the names as it is working now, but want to select the index of said name to pass elsewhere. So like I select the second item in the drop down which says "Second Item". Can i bind the index (1) of this item?

Comment: Try using just the $scope.selected.entity_id